# How to roll back a Windows Azure Cloud Service deployment

Tags: azure, cloud, rollback

As title really, I can't see how you can Roll Back an update to a Windows Azure service/site?
Each "update" has a title, so I'd thought you could see a list of these updates, but I just can't see it listed anywhere?

I use https://manage.windowsazure.com, and these are cloud services.

Comment: If you're loading Web roles, another option is to load the staging deployment and then do a VIP swap. As long as you keep the old deployment running you can easily swap it back. Doesn't work for Worker roles, but in that case you can Stop the old role and then restart it if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Details on Rollbacks can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx#RollbackofanUpdate

To quote:

> Windows Azure provides flexibility in managing services during an update by letting you initiate additional operations on a service, after the initial update request is accepted by the Windows Azure Fabric Controller. A rollback can only be performed when an update (configuration change) or upgrade is in the in progress state on the deployment. An update or upgrade is considered to be in-progress as long as there is at least one instance of the service which has not yet been updated to the new version. To test whether a rollback is allowed, check the value of the `RollbackAllowed` flag, returned by `Get Deployment` and `Get Hosted Service Propertie`s operations, is set to true.
>
> Note
> It only makes sense to call Rollback on an in-place update or upgrade because VIP swap upgrades involve replacing one entire running instance of your service with another. For more information about swapping VIPs, see How to Deploy a Service Upgrade to Production by Swapping VIPs in Windows Azure.

Comment: I am doing updates by creating a package file in Visual studio, and updating uploading these using the "update" feature. Will this mean I can't rollback then?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think that's right. I've never seen an option to roll back and didn't expect to have one.

Comment: I guess the rule here is to backup each set of files when you update, so you rollback by releasing a previous set of files?

Comment: Yeah, you're doing an in place upgrade of the service. So you'll likely need to find the old deployment package (if you have it) and redeploy that to go back. I generally recommend folks archive their old deployment packages specifically for this reason.

Comment: A good way to manage this is to upload your packages and configs to blob storage and deploy from there.  Just put the files in a directory for each deploy then you can easily go back

Comment: The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx#RollbackofanUpdate link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is no stack maintained of your previous deployments, if however your present deployment somehow fails than the fabric may use your previous deployment(It tries to initialize previous states). Your roles are just VHD(Virtual hard disk) with a copy of OS and your installation files running virtually, whenever you update, a new VHD is allotted and the previous is destroyed(if update was successful). Thus there is no way to get the previous deployments(its destroyed). You should store your previous builds locally or on a foundation server just in case you need it like you now.